# Camel bindy: paralelle writing

Tags: parallel-processing, apache-camel, bindy

I'm having a collection of objects that I would like to serialize into a same CSV file.

What is the fastest way to write these objects into the same file ?
Is using `parallelProcessing()` a safe approach ?

Comment: I don't know the answer. Have you tried to see what happens with `parallelProcessing`? I would imagine there would be conflicts in the writing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather implement it with two routes: one with parallel processing collecting data and the second one for writing the collected data into CSV. The latter will be not parallel of course.